# Почему JS работает только на одной странице

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Всем хорошего дня!
Подскажите, кто в курсе...

Есть сайт на WordPress и туда вставил HTML контейнер и подключил внутри скрипт JS. Но беда в том, что этот скрипт работает только на одной странице (на той, где он был первый раз вписан), на других не работает. Так как сам не кодер в JS, подскажите плиз, может кто в курсе?

Пробовал менять переменные, но без результатов.

Ниже прилагаю код:

HTML:

```html
<label for="weather"><h4>Number of persons: </h4></label>
<select id="weather">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var para = document.querySelector('p');

select.addEventListener('change', setWeather);

function setWeather() {
  var choice = select.value;

  if (choice === '1') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 190$';
  } else if (choice === '2') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 120$';
  } else if (choice === '3') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 90$';
  } else if (choice === '4') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 85$';
  } else if (choice === '5') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 85$';
  } else if (choice === '6') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 82$';
  } else if (choice === '7') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 76$';
  } else if (choice === '8') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 74$';
  } else if (choice === '9') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 72$';
  } else if (choice === '10') {
    para.textContent = 'Total: 66$';
  } else {
    para.textContent = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: А JS Вы подключили где? В каком файле? В wordpress общими для всего сайта являются только header.php и footer.php. Если скрипт подключен не в этих файлах и не через functions.php, то естественно, что для всего сайта он работать не будет

Comment: Подключал через Page Builder (создавал контейнер html, вставлял туда сам код html и внутри него подключал скрипт через тэг <script>).

Суть в том, что этот код должен работать на нескольких страницах, но с разными значениями внутри самого кода.

Проще говоря я буду копипастить код на несколько страниц с изменением цифр внутри кода. И при вставке на другую страницу этот код перестает работать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте правильное подключение JS и CSS файлов с помощью [wp_enqueue_script()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script)
Или подключите ваш скрипт в footer.php

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас поизучаю

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно определить подключен скрипт или нет. Попробуйте где то в скрипте сделать `console.log('Hello')`, если в консоли Вы увидите Hello, но скрипт не работает, тогда нужно искать проблему в самом скрипте.
Возможно проблема из за слишком широкого диапазона выборки

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var para = document.querySelector('p');
```

Этот кусок кода слишком неконкретный. Он находит первый селект и первый параграф на странице и пытается что то с ними сделать, соответственно если на странице не один селект и параграф, то скрипт может работать не так, как было задумано.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое! Я все тогда проверю еще раз и разберусь с селектами.